# Where is the Xcode dmg file downloaded to?

Tags: osx-lion, xcode

I'm downloading XCode 4 onto my new Mac (10.7 Lion, so no DVD) from the App Store. It's taking several hours so I'd like to save the `.dmg` onto my laptop, so I can install it again without going through the download process.

Where is the file being downloaded to on my local machine?

Comment: I guess it's `~/Library/Application Support/AppStore/`.

Comment: I checked there and nothing was there...

Comment: oh, you should have mentioned you were downloading it from the AppStore and not from developer.apple.com :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The App Store sends Xcode to your Applications folder as an installer with a custom icon. 
If you are looking for a dmg, that could be the issue. You can save it like any other app - it does not delete itself when you run the installer.

You can see in this screenshot that Install Xcode.app is downloaded to /Applications:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

After I downloaded from the AppStore, I did not find any DMG, but the installation app was (and is) in the `/Applications` folder.

Earlier I deleted it after actually running that installer. But then some time later the AppStore had some issues with an incremental update that came in later, and which then forced me to download the very same thing again, just to be able to download the update. So I decided to leave it sitting there. (And on my Time Machine backup.)

Answer (score 2):

To find downloaded apps from the App Store, run this line on your terminal:

```
lsof | grep -i pkg
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was posted.

Comment: if you download xcode from the App Store, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Lion but for Snow Leopard it would be under `~/Downloads/` - at least mine (just downloaded the latest xcode) ended up there - just like any other downloads I've made.